# A question about locally compact Hausdorff space and metrization

Tags: general-topology

This problem comes from Munkres:

> If a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ is second countable, then it is metrizable. At the same time, it has a one-point compactification $Y$. Is $Y$ metrizable?

I tried to prove that "$Y$ is second countable" but failed. But when I try to find some counterexamples, it seems not easy, too (I checked come examples, but all of them satisfy the requirement).
Is the proposition right or not? If not, is there any counterexample?

Comment: The correct spelling is "metrizable" instead of "matrizable".

Comment: Hint: $X$ has an exhaustion by compact sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are referring to is actually **true**. So, a counterexample doesn't exist!

**Hint:** To show that the one-point compactification $X^*$ is second-countable, you just need to construct a countable neighborhood basis at $\infty\in X^*$. To do this, try using the fact: A Hausdorff space $X$ is locally compact **iff** $X$ admits a basis of *precompact* open subsets. Can you go from here?

> A subset $P\subseteq X$ is said to be *precompact* if its closure $\overline{P}$ is compact in $X$.

Comment: Thanks for error correction and hint! I solve it with your help!

Comment: I'm glad to be of help (: